# Fatal error: Call to undefined function phpinclude()

Tags: php, header

Hey i am using this code

```
<?php
header("Location: ../index.php");
?>
```

and it is just coming up with this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function phpinclude() in /home/nzcraftn/public_html/filenz/upload/index.php on line 1
```

What went wrong?

Comment: the error seems to be in `index.php`. Show some codes from your `index.php` instead

Comment: The error says it all pretty clear - index.php (at line 1) tried to call a function named `phpinclude()` which - surprisingly, doesn't exist.

Comment: That code at the top is the index.php code.

Comment: You might have more than one file that is named `index.php`. Look into the other file you're redirecting to and show *that* code. It doesn't help to ask about the wrong code.

Comment: In case anyone else runs into this issue like I just did, it's an encoding issue. When editing the file in Notepad++ it looked fine, but in regular Notepad there were no linebreaks. You can either add the linebreaks using notepad, or change the encoding style to match your server (UTF-8 without BOM is probably what you want).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i guess you've got `<?phpinclude(...)   ?>` when it must be `<?php include(...)   ?>`

Comment: try to look on this code in another designer. may be theres some strange issue with linebreaks